# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to import a csv file into my table below, and I keep getting this Error:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tmdb_5000_movies_production_companies_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (production_companies)=([{iso_3166_1: US, name: United States of America}]) already exists.
>   CONTEXT:  COPY tmdb_5000_movies, line 5

-- Create New Table

```
CREATE TABLE tmdb_5000_movies (
    "budget" INT,   
    "genres" VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    "homepage" VARCHAR UNIQUE,  
    "id" INT,   
    "keywords" VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    "original_language" VARCHAR,    
    "original_title" VARCHAR,
    "overview" VARCHAR,
    "popularity" DEC,
    "production_companies" VARCHAR UNIQUE,      
    "production_countries" VARCHAR UNIQUE,      
    "release_date" DATE,    
    "revenue" BIGINT,
    "runtime" INT,
    "spoken_languages" VARCHAR UNIQUE,  
    "status" VARCHAR,
    "tagline" VARCHAR,
    "title" VARCHAR,    
    "vote_average" DEC, 
    "vote_count" INT
);
```

I have tried to change the data types, but I don't know what other way to go. Pretty new to this and any type of help I can get will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If a column has a `UNIQUE` constraint, no two table rows are allowed to have the same value in that column (unless it is the `NULL` value).

Either remove the `UNIQUE` constraint or sanitize the data.

If you want a *combination* of columns to be unique, you have to define a `UNIQUE` constraint over several columns:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   col1 type1,
   col2 type2,
   UNIQUE (col1, col2)
);
```

Moreover, each table should have a primary key.